# paypal mobile express redirects to web instead of mobile

Tags: ios, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

my app supports paypal payment and I use mobile express payout and now I see that it force loads to web even when I mention "_express-checkout-mobile"

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout-mobile&useraction=commit&token=EC-***************

Comment: what schema you used for then because for me webview never hit my app delegate method openURL.

Comment: Sorry, I moved from that project shortly after posting this query.

Answer (score 1):

PayPal uses browser detection to decide whether to show the mobile flow or the desktop flow.  If you're using a webview inside of an app, you need to be sure that the webview is sending a User-Agent header in the HTTP request that identifies the browser as a mobile browser.

Comment: [request addValue:@"User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8B117 Safari/6531.22.7" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];   No use. Still it takes to web

Comment: it just forces to web as before. even when webview inside app or routed to safari