# Paypal adaptive payment not working in mobile

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm trying to set a paypal adaptive payment flow to create a Chained payment. After many troubles the desktop version of my payment works correctly, it sends payment to all the receivers and it redirect correctly to my site. My problem now is in real mobile browsers ( setting user agent of my desktop browser solve all the problems, but this naturally it isn't the real mobile user experience). 
This is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Paypal test</title>
</head>

<body>
<!--MINI-->
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/apdg.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    //this function register the order in my system
    function saveOrder() {

                //call an internal api to get the paypal api key for this transaction
                $.ajax({
                  url: "http://www.example.com/ajax/getPayKey.php",
                  success: function(datakey) {

                       arrData = datakey.split("|");
                       var paykey=arrData[0];

                       //with the obtained api key i set the value of the hidden field in the form
                       $("#paykey").val(paykey);

                  }

                });




    }   


    var returnFromPayPal = function(){

        // returning from paypal flow i need to know the transaction status to redirect the user to the correct page in my site
        $.ajax({
              url: "<?php echo URL_SITO; ?>/ajax/PaymentDetails.php?pay_key="+ $("#paykey").val(),
              success: function(data_return) {

                 //with the url returned i redirect user
                 document.location.href=data_return;
              }

            });

    }

    //init the paypal flow 
    var dgFlowMini = new PAYPAL.apps.DGFlowMini({trigger: 'submitBtn', expType: 'mini', callbackFunction: 'returnFromPayPal'});

</script>

<!--Start pay key process-->
<div onclick="saveOrder();">Pay Order</div>

<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay" target="PPDGFrame" class="standard" id="paypal_form_adaptive">
    <!--Start payment flow-->
    <input type="image" id="submitBtn" value="Pay with PayPal" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif">
    <input id="type" type="hidden" name="expType" value="mini">
    <input id="paykey" type="hidden" name="paykey" value="insert_pay_key">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have read in paypal documentation that i can use three types of flow for an adaptive payments, i have found problems with all this flow types. I have choose the "mini" options beacause it is the nearest to solution.
Anyway, with the code above i mostly complete the flow, the "mini" open a new tab in my Iphone, i complete the payment but the redirect is wrong. Paypal returns in my payment page but the  `callbackFunction: 'returnFromPayPal'`
is never called. Without callback i can't redirect user.

How i can do to complete correctly this flow on mobile?
There is someone how had complete the flow on mobile?

PAYMENT FLOW DETAILS

I have to create a chained payment flow, 1 sender and 2 receivers (a primary and a secondary), the flow will be something like:

sender buy an item -> it pays the primary receveri -> the primary pays a percentage to secondary receiver (the web-app owner).

This is my business kind and as you can see it's a simply chained flow and it works correctly in deskotp version.

What is the flow tecnhically to achive my business type?

sender buy an item -> i call the first api to create the payment and retrive a paykey -> with paykey i send a form to instantiate a mini browser flow -> sender complete payment in mini browser -> mini browser return and launch a callback js function-> in callback js function i call another paypal api to get payment details -> analizing the payment details i know if the transaction is completed or not -> if transaction is completed i have to redirect user to a specific page on my site, if transaction isn't completed i have to redirect the user to another page.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Safari for iOS, you can try using a debugger for Safari https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/ . 
Another thing that you should consider is to send a User-Agent header in the HTTP request that identifies the browser as a mobile browser. ( [paypal mobile express redirects to web instead of mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18635776/paypal-mobile-express-redirects-to-web-instead-of-mobile) )